# How to ensure that only a certain section of a UIScrollView appears to slide?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I use a UIScrollView that has horizontal sliding enabled.

The Heading of the scroll view is `Instructions for Using this App`

And below that, I have `instructions`, one instruction per "page".

When the user scrolls horizontally, new instructions show. However, during this horizontal scrolling, the "Instructions for Using this App" from the second page also appears to move.

```
Instructions for Using this App     <--- I do not want this to appear to slide

1. Instruction number 1. XYZ...
   more text more text more text
   more text more text more text    <--- I want only this to slide
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place separate UIView (probably UILabel in your case) on top of your UIScrollView, so your UI hierarchy will be something like:

```
UIView (screen)
   UILabel (header)
   UIScrollView (scrolled content)
```